# How to merge two items from a List into only one?

Tags: java, collections, merge

Supposing I have the following list:

`A | B | C | D` or `the | temperature | is | 100 | °F | today`

I want to merge two attributes into one, something like this:

`A | BC | D` or `the | temperature | is | 100°F | today`

How can I achieve this? The Collection can be changed, if needed.

Comment: So which part are you struggling with, seems like a pretty straightforward thing to do?

Comment: Give more example. Why you merge `BC` and `100°F`?  What rule govern this?

Comment: @J-16 SDiz This two are only examples and the rules to merge this is not important. My doubt is only how to merge the two items. Can be another words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if what your trying to do is take an element and its successor and merge them, this should work:

```
String i = list.get(iIndex); 
String j = list.get(iIndex + 1);
i= i.concat(j);
list.set(iIndex,i);
list.remove(iIndex + 1);
```

Comment: This assumes that only adjacent elements need to be merged. Not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Pangea Yes, at the moment, only the next or previous elements need to be merged (if matches some rules)

Comment: @Renato Dinhani Conceição This code only takes care of merging with next element. You can either add previous behavior to this code or you can use the generic code (u need to modify it little bit to handle error scenarios) I've provided. The concept is the same though

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised there was no standard API method to do this. Oh well, here's my home-brewed solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana" });
    System.out.println(fruits); // Prints [Apple, Orange, Pear, Banana]
    System.out.println(merge(fruits, 1)); // Prints [Apple, OrangePear, Banana]
    System.out.println(merge(fruits, 3)); // Throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Cannot merge last element
}

public static List<String> merge(final List<String> list, final int index) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot merge empty list");
    } else if (index + 1 >= list.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot merge last element");
    } else {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(list);
        result.set(index, list.get(index) + list.get(index + 1));
        result.remove(index + 1);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct api for this. But the below can get you started

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * @param toIndex the index of the element that other items are merged with. The final merged item is set at this index.
     * @param indices a comma separated list of indices of the items that need be merged with item at <code>toIndex</code>
     */
    public static void merge(int toIndex, int... indices) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list.get(toIndex));
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            sb.append(list.get(indices[i]));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {

            list.remove(indices[i]);
        }
        list.set(toIndex, sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");
        merge(1,2);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: what about in cases where you want to combined indices i...j into k such that k > i...j? wouldn't removing the indices shift the index numbers for the subsequent list items?

Comment: try merge(3,2), it should throw you a nice java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: wespiserA - both of your concerns are valid but SO is meant to provide hints not complete production ready solutions.